# Can a circuit "just stop working" after not using it for a long time?

Tags: mosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXriVz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I had a very simple circuit that used a mosfet with an arduino to power a motor. The whole thing is run off of a 12v supply (5v reg. added to supply power to the arduino). The circuit was working fine before (a few months ago), but when I tried turning it on today, the motor wouldn't start. Here are my findings:

Multimeter says the motor wires (w/o motor connected) are in fact getting the needed 12v, but it drops to under a volt when I reconnect the motor.

I tried connecting my motor directly to the 12v supply, but it just made a big spark (I am not sure if the motor actually started, but it should not have sparked the way it did).

Nothing 'smells' like it is burned out, and nothing got abnormally hot. Does anyone have any idea as to what could have happened (I used the same PSU as before).

Comment: If the motor is not working when powered directly (I assume it is DC motor, isn't it?)- it is dead. What is the question here?

Comment: I tested it with two motors (same model bought at the same time). Neither of them work, so I doubt it is that.

Comment: How could it be anything else? The motor doesn't do anything when connected to power!

Comment: What are these motors? Are they DC? Brushed?

Comment: I didn't say that the motor didn't work when connected to power, I said it sparked abnormally. I just check it again, and the motor did start when connected directly.

Comment: @Eugene DC brushed motors

Comment: This is the motor: http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/radioshack-super-speed-9-18vdc-hobby-motor/2730256.html#.VYsQHflViko

Comment: Do you have a flyback diode over your mosfet?

Comment: Uh... no. I know I should, but I still get 12v when I check with my multimeter, so the mosfets are okay, right?

Comment: The motors have a max current... I am using a 3 amp supply, but that does not mean I am forcing 3 amps through the motor, right? The motor takes what it needs depending on the voltage.

Comment: You better show your circuit.

Comment: The motor's max RPM depends on it's voltage... it's max *torque* depends on the current available.

Comment: @rdtsc - so I can connect a 12v motor to a 1 amp or 1000 amp supply, but it will only draw what it needs?

Comment: Disconnect the motor and try turning it. Circuits are OK with lack of use; mechanical parts can seize. This draws high current and can damage the circuit.

Comment: The motor seems fine - I connected it directly to the supply

Comment: You should have a flyback diode. It may be that your mosfet has been fried and is acting as a largish resistor. Try measuring the resistance between the source and drain of the mosfet when it is turned on. It should probably be < 1 ohm..

Comment: Essentially, yes @electricviolin. No-load, motors draw little current. Current increases as motor load increases. Up to the limit of the motor.

Comment: @avl_sweden - I measured it to be between 2.5 and 3 ohms... is that bad?

Comment: I made a small mistake in drawing the circuit... I noticed a tiny resistor in my circuit, and then discovered that it was a transistor rather than a mosfet... I fixed the schematic to match

Comment: Do you have the current limit set too low on your power supply?

Comment: I am actually just using a laptop charger - it is a 12V 3A, the motor shouldn't draw more than an amp

Comment: It might draw more than 1A when its starting.

Comment: That true, but either way 3A should be more than enough

Comment: It has worked with this psu before

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25172/discussion-on-question-by-electricviolin-can-a-circuit-just-stop-working-after).

Comment: 3 ohms seems way too much to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your circuit that should age while in storage.

In fact, those components would typically have a very long life even under load.

Some components, such as batteries and capacitors, can age while being stored, especially if stored in a hot location.

The lubricant in the motors would age slightly, the metal might corrode in an aggressive environemnt, and dirt could aggregate in the moving parts, but unless they've been stored in an extremely aggressive environment, the answer to your question is simply no, a circuit doesn't stop working just because it hasn't been used for a long time, not even the motors.